# How to change "printed list" into dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to convert my "printed list" into a dtaframe:

1st: I import a lift of tickers/symbols from a folder
import yfinance as yf

```
with open("/Users/AB/OD/Earnings/tickers.txt") as fh:
    tick1 = fh.read().split()
```

(here is an example of ticker to be saved in the txt file:
'ABCL',
'ABST',
'ACM',
'ADAP',
'ADCT',
'ADV'
)

2nd: I need to get the marketCap for all these tickers, however I dont know how to convert it into one big dataframe: headers: 'ticker'; 'marketCap'.

This is the code I could get, but not sure how to proceed:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

test = tick1

for ticker in test:
    try:
        marketCap = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap']
        print(marketCap)
    except:
        pass
```

If the marketCap is not available, we can simply skip it. we Don require them into the data frame.

Comment: what do you get with `print()` ? You coudl show example.

Comment: you could append to some list (or maybe to dictonary as `data[ticker] = marketCap`) and later (after `for`-loop) it may need to use `DataFrame(some_list)` or `pd.concat(some_list)` or other function to convert it to `DataFrame` - all depends on what type of data you have in `marketCap` - `pandas.DataFrame`, `pandas.Series`, `list`, `dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Before loop you could create list.
2. Inside loop you could append to this list
3. After loop you could convert this list to DataFrame

And converting depends on what type of data you get in `marketCap` - `pandas.DataFrame`, `pandas.Series`, `list`, `dictionary`.

In your code it needs `pandas.concat(some_list)`

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

test = ['ABCL', 'ABST', 'ACM', 'ADAP', 'ADCT', 'ADV']

# --- before loop ---

data = []

# --- loop ---

for ticker in test:
    try:
        marketCap = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap']
        print(marketCap)
        data.append(marketCap)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('skip:', ticker, ex)

# --- after loop ---

serie = pd.concat(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(serie)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
       marketCap
ABCL  1870047360
ABST   346576800
ACM   9633939456
ADAP   246278048
ADCT   641943744
ADV   1593755008
```

Comment: Hi Furas! Thank you so much, this is an epic solution. It works!!!